# Using truncate \ find

Tags: find, grep

This command won't work:

```
$ truncate -s 0 $(find . -size +1c type -f -exec grep -LwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} +)

"find: paths must precede expression: type
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
truncate: missing file operand
Try `truncate --help' for more information."
```

Note: I understand whitespace could cause issues.

```
$ rm $(find . -size +1b -type f -exec grep -LwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} +)
```

works properly but it's not what I need as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use command substitution on the output of `find`. Since you're already using GNU specific options:

```
find . -size +1c -type f -exec grep -LZwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} + |
  xargs -r0 truncate -s 0
```

Answer (score 3):

That error was caused merely by the dash being in the wrong place ("type -f" vs "-type f").  Use:

```
truncate -s 0 $(find . -size +1c -type f -exec grep -LwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} +)
```

To handle file names with spaces:

```
find . -size +1c -type f -exec grep -LwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} + | while IFS= read -r fname ; do truncate -s 0 "$fname" ; done
```

Comment: +1 but why do you have the `while` loop in `{}` ?

Comment: @terdon OK.  Removed.